# inverse function , asymptotics ..

Tags: functional-equations

let be a function given by $ f^{-1} (x) = \sqrt x + G(x) $

with  $ G(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{N}a_{n} \sin(nx+ \pi/4) $ finite fourier series with N big

my questio is , if for $ x \rightarrow \infty$ the function can be asymptotically defined by $ f(x) \sim x^{2} $

on condition that for every 'x' $ G(x) \le \le \sqrt x$ so the most importan term is the SMOOTH term defined by the square root of 'x'

Answer (score 1):

Well, $G(x)$ is obviously bounded (for example by $\sum_{n=0}^N |a_n|$, there might be a tigther one), so for large $x$, the *relative* error will go to zero. Not the absolute error, though.

Comment: yo mean $ e_{relative}= e_{real}-e_{error}/e_{real} $ and $ e_{absolute}= e_{real}-e_{error} $ ?? thanks for your answer fgp

Comment: @JoseGarcia Yes.